# Can I use a router to wirelessly connect to the internet and then share it via Ethernet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

So I have 2 routers.

Router A and Router B.

Router A is connected to the internet.

Router B is connected to the desktop via Ethernet.

From the perspective of Router B, can I wirelessly connect to Router A, and then share the internet connection via the Ethernet?

In other words, can Router B function like those USB WiFi receivers?

Answer (score 0):

With a normal router there is no way that would work.

Unless router B has a special configuration for this, but that would be very unusual.
(The router would have to do something completely different from its normal way of operation. It would require having a second set of firmware in the router specifically for this.)

I have heard rumors that there exist routers that can do it, but I have never seen one for real.
In fact nobody I know has ever seen them either.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, sure, but not many routers support this out of the box. The wireless interface would have to work as a client instead of an access point, so look for an option called 'client mode' or similar in your router's wireless configuration. If no such option exists, you may need to install custom firmware that does allow you to use the router as a wireless client, such as [DD-WRT](http://dd-wrt.com).